# No animations on GNOME 3

Tags: gnome, 18.04, animations

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME 3 from the box. And now I can see, that I have no animations. I checked Gnome Tweak Tool, dconf editor, everything is ok. Nothing extensions doesn't help. I don't remember if there were animations before. Maybe it happened after some extentions were been installed or after playing with compiz (I didn't know before, that it works only on Unity). I already removed compiz-config, thought it will help, but no. What can help me?